# Парсинг файла на python

Tags: python, парсер, поиск

Необходимо сделать парсер на Python который будет искать в определенной базе данных https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMnqw.png по номеру телефона имена ( просто вывод строки ). У меня получился такой код :

```
a = int(input("Введите номер телефона: "))
file=open('GET CONTACT.txt','r')
text=file.read()
if a in text:
    print (a)
```

но почему - то он крашит , либо выдает ошибку .

Comment: Какую выдает ошибку? Уточните ваш вопрос

Comment: А что имеется в виду в четвертой строчке?

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("data.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    data = file.readlines()
    
a = input("Введите номер телефона: ") # <- убрал int

for line in data:
    if a in line:
        print(line)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй в цикле проверять твое условие, и файл закрывать надо.

```
a = input("Введите номер телефона: ")
file=open('GET_CONTACT.txt','r',encoding='utf8')
for text in file:
        if a in text:
            print (text)
file.close()
```